# Magento 2: attribute default checkbox toggle

Tags: magento2, attributes, multistore, default, default-values

I have 2 websites sharing the same Magento 2 install. I have data in the short description on one store that I don't want to use anymore as I have the short description defined correctly at All Stores level. How can I check the box on short description for all the products in the one store to have it use 'default'?

Answer (score 1):

If you're asking for a "quick" way to have the stores use the default/website values again, then you'd be looking for a way to actually just *delete* the data at that store scope; the absence of store scope data implies that it should fall back to the default/website values.

Essentially you'd be wanting to remove data from tables like such (please, for the love of god, take a DB backup before running anything like this...):

```
DELETE FROM `catalog_product_entity_text` WHERE `store_id` = 2
```

where `catalog_product_entity_text` is the table containing all text attribute data for products, and `store_id` is of course the store view's ID number. This would remove *all* text attribute data for products on that store view.

Comment: I updated the table `catalog_product_entity_text` to remove the text data I did not want but doing that did not check the default checkbox for short description.